# SPARQL return reversed resource/objects

Tags: sparql, rdf

Suppose you know `:hasFriend` should be symmetric, but you don't have a schema and it is not always coded as such in the dataset. I can use a construct to reconstruct all friendships:

```
construct {  ?x :hasFriend ?y 
 ?y :hasFriend ?x}  where {
  ?x :hasFriend ?y
}
```

How can I do something similar in a `select` such that the result is returned?

Comment: not sure if I understand, what is the expected result in the `SELECT` query? A single column or 2 columns or ... please provide an example

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you:

- Want to return the relationship as symmetrical from a SELECT query
- Do not have the use of a reasoner to leverage [owl:SymmetricProperty](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl-ref/#SymmetricProperty-def)
- The relationship may only be stored in one direction

considering the following data is inserted like so:

```
prefix nepr:   <https://aws.amazon.com/neptune/resource#>
prefix nepo:   <https://aws.amazon.com/neptune/ontology/>

insert data {

    nepr:John  nepo:hasFriend nepr:Bob ;
            nepo:hasFriend nepr:Mike ;
            nepo:hasFriend nepr:Sarah .
            
    nepr:Sarah nepo:hasFriend nepr:John ;
            nepo:hasFriend nepr:Nicole ;
            nepo:hasFriend nepr:Melissa .
            
}
```

You can use a UNION, like so:

```
prefix nepr:   <https://aws.amazon.com/neptune/resource#>
prefix nepo:   <https://aws.amazon.com/neptune/ontology/>

select DISTINCT * where {

    {
        ?x nepo:hasFriend ?y .
    }
    UNION
    {
        ?y nepo:hasFriend ?x .
    }

}
```

Comment: `?x nepo:hasFriend|^nepo:hasFriend ?y .` would be the property path variant